# Python boto3 - adding rule description under Security Group

Tags: boto3, aws-security-group

I'm trying to create a rule with description but Boto3 doesn't seem to support it. Please check the syntax below:

```
 securityGroup.authorize_ingress(IpProtocol='tcp', FromPort=22, ToPort=22, CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0', Description='SSH Access')
```

Here is the error:

> botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
>   Unknown parameter in input: "Description", must be one of: CidrIp, FromPort, GroupId, GroupName, IpPermissions, IpProtocol, SourceSecurityGroupName, SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId, ToPort, DryRun

I can add description to the security group just fine but not to the rule. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.SecurityGroup.authorize_ingress) for the detailed example. There isn't a `Description` key on the top level but you can find it from the value of `IpPermissions` and `IpRanges`.

```
response = security_group.authorize_ingress(
    CidrIp='string',
    FromPort=123,
    GroupName='string',
    IpPermissions=[
        {
            'FromPort': 123,
            'IpProtocol': 'string',
            'IpRanges': [
                {
                    'CidrIp': 'string',
                    'Description': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'Ipv6Ranges': [
                {
                    'CidrIpv6': 'string',
                    'Description': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'PrefixListIds': [
                {
                    'Description': 'string',
                    'PrefixListId': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'ToPort': 123,
            'UserIdGroupPairs': [
                {
                    'Description': 'string',
                    'GroupId': 'string',
                    'GroupName': 'string',
                    'PeeringStatus': 'string',
                    'UserId': 'string',
                    'VpcId': 'string',
                    'VpcPeeringConnectionId': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    IpProtocol='string',
    SourceSecurityGroupName='string',
    SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId='string',
    ToPort=123,
    DryRun=True|False
)
```

So, in your case it should be look like as follows.

```
response = security_group.authorize_ingress(
    IpPermissions=[
        {
            'FromPort': 22,
            'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
            'IpRanges': [
                {
                    'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0',
                    'Description': 'SSH Access'
                },
            ],
            'ToPort': 22,
            ]
        },
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a rule description, you can use IpRanges block.

> **IpRanges** - A set of IP permissions to specify multiple rules and a description for the rule.

```
'IpRanges': [
  {
     'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0',
     'Description': 'SSH Access'
  }
]
```